# xattr produce error when clear rights

Tags: bash, macos, xattr

I have directory with inherited rights:

```
drwxrwxrwx+  5 root           admin    170 Feb 16 18:27 autotests
0: group:everyone inherited deny add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit
```

So I want to clear extended rights and do this on parent directory:

```
xattr -rc .
```

But I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'com.apple.FinderInfo'
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using [chmod](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html)

Comment: I just marked this as not useful since you don't propose a whole solution, you just point in some direction without stepts to reproduce...